# Fix inconsistent result between windows and linux for detectAndCompute in opencv python + ImageMagick

Tags: python, opencv, imagemagick, opencv3.0

I have been fighting with this for a while without any luck. I am converting a  pdf  using wand library (ImageMagick) in python and calculating the features using open cv2 for later on some other image matching. The is the following

```
from wand.image import Image
import cv2 as cv
import logging

with Image(filename="processing.pdf[0]", resolution=500) as img:
    img.compression_quality = 100
    img.format = "png"
    img.save(filename="temp.png")

detector = cv.BRISK_create()

img1 = cv.imread("temp.png", 0)

kp1, desc1 = detector.detectAndCompute(img1, None)

logging.warn('img1 - %{0} features'.format(len(kp1)))
```

For some reason I get different number of features in windows and linux
Windows

```
2018-08-22 01:45:21,235 - INFO - img1 - %44509 features
```

Linux

```
2018-08-22 05:41:54,891 - INFO - img1 - %48371 features
```

I am using the following dependency in python

```
opencv-python==3.4.0
Wand==0.4.4
```

ImageMagick 6.8.9 installed.

If I use the same image (copy the image from windows machine to linux machine) and execute the code without converting PDF, the number of features is almost the same.

I know there are differences between the linux/windows codecs however I am looking for a decent solution or workaround to make the behavior as close as possible to between both environments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have differing versions of **ghostscript** which **ImageMagick** uses to read PDFs. I think you should maybe omit compression quality for PNGs as it's always lossless. Also check image has same number of channels and same mean/stddev before and after saving - those flags on `cv2.imread()` are hard to get right.

Comment: You could also run **ImageMsgick**'s `compare` on `temp.png` from Windows versus that produced on Linux...

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you for your suggestion. After run the ImageMagick's compare I get an output image, so do images are definitely different depending on where I am generating them. I also tried removing compression quality geting the same behavior. I tried setting colorspace to  img.colorspace = 'rgb' getting the same results. Any other suggestions would be really appreciate it. I am using the same ImageMagick version in both sides.

Comment: Ghostscript device rendering would most likely be the cause. Try running the `gs` utility directly on each box, and use Mark's `compare` technique to isolate the difference. A resolution of 500 is rather large, and the [smallest artifact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact) could become exaggerated.